# How to define the shift operator for an arbitrary stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X=(X_n,n\in \mathbb{N})$ be an arbitary $E$-valued stochastic process defined on probability space $\Omega$. Then how can we defined the shift operator?

Usually, $\Omega = E^\mathbb{N}$ and $X$ is taken to be the identity operator on $\Omega$ so that the shift operator can be defined by $\tau:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ where $(\omega_n,n\in \mathbb{N}) \mapsto (\omega_{n+1},n\in \mathbb{N})$ so that $X_n = X_0 \circ \tau^n$. However, how would we define $\tau$ if we had a general $\Omega$ and $X$?

Comment: I'd say something like this: Let $X=(X_t)_{t \in T}$ be a stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ with values in some space $E$. Let's say $T \subset \mathbb R$. Assume that $\forall_{\omega \in \Omega} \forall_{t \in T} \exists!_{ \tau_t(\omega) \in \Omega } \forall_{s \in T : s+t \in T}$ such that $X_{t+s}(\omega) = X_s(\tau_t(\omega))$ (for example when $\Omega$ is a canonical space for our process, so when $\Omega = E^T$ or $\Omega = C(E,\mathbb R)$ and $X_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$ ) that assumption is satisfied. Then I'd say that $\tau_t : \Omega \to \Omega$ is a shift operator.

Comment: The assumption seems hard to justify when $X$ is not the canonical process.